# SELECT COUNT different sub-rows in every row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, rows

I have an actor-movies database, and I have to select the people that are actor, director, and the ones who have produced movies in most different countries. This is my Schema:

**Movie**(id_movie, title, id_director(FK), year, duration, country, facebook_likes, imdb_score, gross, budget)

**Actor_Movie**(id_actor(FK), id_movie(FK))

**Person**(id_person, name, facebook_likes)

**Actor**(id_actor(FK))

**Director**(id_director(FK))

And this is what I've done but I don't receive what I expect:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM Person AS p
     , Movie AS m
     , Actor AS a
     , Director AS d
 WHERE p.id_person = m.id_director
   AND p.id_person = a.id_actor
   AND p.id_person = d.id_director
 GROUP 
    BY m.country
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(DISTINCT m.country) DESC
 LIMIT 5;
```

Thank you!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You need to join. And not to filter by using a where clause. And why are you grouping? You dont have any aggr functions. And you where clause doesnt make sense. ID_Person can hopefully never be equal to id_director,id_actor

Comment: id_actor and id_director are foreign keys of id_person. It must be equal in some values. What I do in where clause is joining, it's the same as JOIN but done in other form